# Foreach only computes first row and discards the rest

Tags: php, mysql

there are pre-defined fields and users can as well create new fields and insert values , so what I want to do is to get all the columns than remove only the pre-defined fields so that only the fields the users has created can remain in the query and i would like to get the sum of the remaining fields . The problem is that only the first row gets processed and discards the remaining rows since there are many rows that meet the where condition.

```
$added_income = 0;
$added_income1 = 0;

// total Salary 
$result868 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM $income WHERE Company='".$company."' AND ( Month='".$March."' OR Month='".$April."' OR Month='".$May."' OR Month='".$June."' OR Month='".$July."' OR Month='".$August."' OR Month='".$September."' OR Month='".$October."' OR Month='".$November."' OR Month='".$December."') AND Year='".$Year1."'");                                             

$rows54 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result868);

$removeKeys = array('ID', 'Employee_Number', 'Month', 'Year', 'Company', 'Status', 'payment_cycle', 'Payslip_Number', 'House1', 'closing', 'generated', 'Salary','Bonus','Commission','Housing_Allowance','House1','Transport_Allowance','Travel_Allowance','Vehicle_Allowance','Vehicle1','Cellphone_Allowance','Entertainment_Allowance','Company_Car','Medical_Allowance','Leave_payout','Overtime_Hours','Overtime','Cost_to_company');

foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
   unset($rows54[$key]);
}

foreach($rows54 as $x => $x_value) {    
    $added_income = $added_income + $x_value;
}
```

Comment: well - you only fetch the first row, so only the first one *can* be processed

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches __one row__.

Comment: What is all that `removekeys` rubbish. If you only want a specific column then do a `SELECT col1,col2,col3` and the query will run faster as well

Comment: There are pre-defined columns and columns that are dynamically added by user , So I want only want the sum of the dynamically added columns

Comment: Well in that case leave the `select *` but call the `removeKeys` array an `ignoreKeys` array and test if a field is in the `ignoreKeys` array and if it is erm... ignore it in the calc

Comment: This does highlight the likelyhood that you have committed a bit of a database design error

Comment: I would love to see the code that creates columns dynamically in your table when a user adds data and you add columns to the table. ___WOW bet thats a doozie___ Maybe if you post that code we can keep it in the _Rookie errors you should definitely avoid list_

Comment: i'd say that with user-added-columns, a database design error is not just a lightlyhood but a certainty.

Comment: Would I also be correct if I said I thought you were also creating a new table for each user as well?

Comment: Not sure what is happening here, but a few extra tables, a `SUM()` and a `GROUP BY` you can probably get what you need in one line of sql.

Comment: @jeroen Welcome to the party

Comment: And I bet some poor shmuck who does not know better is paying you for this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because it is fetching only the first row

Put the lines

```
$rows54 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result868);

$removeKeys = array('ID', 'Employee_Number', 'Month', 'Year', 'Company', 'Status', 'payment_cycle', 'Payslip_Number', 'House1', 'closing', 'generated', 'Salary','Bonus','Commission','Housing_Allowance','House1','Transport_Allowance','Travel_Allowance','Vehicle_Allowance','Vehicle1','Cellphone_Allowance','Entertainment_Allowance','Company_Car','Medical_Allowance','Leave_payout','Overtime_Hours','Overtime','Cost_to_company');

foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
   unset($rows54[$key]);
}

foreach($rows54 as $x => $x_value) {    
    $added_income = $added_income + $x_value;
}
```

inside a while loop like this

```
$added_income = 0;
$added_income1 = 0;

// total Salary 
$result868 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM $income WHERE Company='".$company."' AND ( Month='".$March."' OR Month='".$April."' OR Month='".$May."' OR Month='".$June."' OR Month='".$July."' OR Month='".$August."' OR Month='".$September."' OR Month='".$October."' OR Month='".$November."' OR Month='".$December."') AND Year='".$Year1."'");                                             

while($rows54 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result868)){

 $removeKeys = array('ID', 'Employee_Number', 'Month', 'Year', 'Company', 'Status', 'payment_cycle', 'Payslip_Number', 'House1', 'closing', 'generated', 'Salary','Bonus','Commission','Housing_Allowance','House1','Transport_Allowance','Travel_Allowance','Vehicle_Allowance','Vehicle1','Cellphone_Allowance','Entertainment_Allowance','Company_Car','Medical_Allowance','Leave_payout','Overtime_Hours','Overtime','Cost_to_company');

 foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
    unset($rows54[$key]);
 }

 foreach($rows54 as $x => $x_value) {    
     $added_income = $added_income + $x_value;
 }
}
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are saying. Show the OP a complete recoded section. Otherwise OP will be doing a fetch inside a while loop doing the fetch

Comment: Good enough for a +1? :P

Comment: It was sarcasm my friend, not begging

Comment: In that case UV, we need a few more members with a sence of humour

Comment: That's so true @RiggsFolly. Happy days to you too

Comment: plus one for soft sarcasm